# How do I fill a Gridview with a BaseAdapter in Android?

Tags: android, gridview, calendar, adapter

I'm trying to program a calendar with a database connection and events filling in that calendar. When I test my program it just gets a black screen on bluestacks, and then goes to the homescreen. This is my code

```
class KalenderData {

    int day;
    int month;
    String events;
    int eventDate;

    KalenderData(int day,int month, String events, int eventDate) {
        this.day = day;
        this.month = month;
        this.events = events;
        this.eventDate = eventDate;
    }

}

class KalenderAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<KalenderData> list;
    Context context;

    KalenderAdapter(Context context) {

        this.context = context;
        list = new ArrayList<KalenderData>();

        int[] amountOfDays = {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
        int[] month = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
        int[] days;

        for(int k = 0; k < month.length; k++) {

            for (int i = 0; i < amountOfDays[i]; i++) {

                days = new int[amountOfDays[month[k]]];

                for (int l = 0; l < amountOfDays[month[k]]; l++) {

                    days[l] = (amountOfDays[month[k]]) - amountOfDays[month[k] - (l + 1)];

                    //Konstruktor ist falsch initialisiert
                    KalenderData tempData = new KalenderData(days[l], month[k], null, 0);
                    list.add(tempData);

                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    class ViewHolder{

        TextView data;

        ViewHolder(View view){

            data = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.day);

        }

    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_day, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }else{

            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();

        }

        KalenderData temp = list.get(position);
        holder.data.setText(temp.day);

        return row;
    }
}
```

}

the xml file for each grid just got 1 textview in it with the id day.

single_day.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

`<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/day"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="hello"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"/>
```

`/LinearLayout>`

activity_calendar.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.damian.schulkalender.Kalender">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<GridView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Calendar"
    android:numColumns="7"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:smoothScrollbar="false" />
```

Comment: Your adapter looks ok.  Please could you add the code for the Activity or Fragment where you are using the Adapter to the question?

Comment: Why is this tagged as ASP.NET when you're writing Java code for Android?

Comment: i added the xml files to the post